# Delete whole Array by bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

We have a plugin list of array and it's called "availablePlugins".
And we have another file that has all plugin list of arrays.
Then we need to **delete whole array of the unavailable plugins**.

```
availablePlugins=("plugin1", "plugin3", "plugin5");
```

It's the **Available Plugin's slug** array.

There is a plugin.php file ( another file ) and we need to remove some arrays by NOT available plugin array

```
apply_filters('plugins_filter', Array(
   Array(
   'name' => 'My Plugin1'
   'slug' => 'plugin1'
   'version' => '1.0.2,
   ... etc
  ),
  Array(
   'name' => 'My Plugin2'
   'slug' => 'plugin2'
   'version' => '1.0.2,
   ... etc
  ),
  Array(
  'name' => 'My Plugin3'
  'slug' => 'plugin3'
  'version' => '1.0.2,
  ... etc
  ),
  Array(
   'name' => 'My Plugin4'
   'slug' => 'plugin4'
   'version' => '1.0.2,
   ... etc
  ),
  Array(
   'name' => 'My Plugin5'
   'slug' => 'plugin5'
   'version' => '1.0.2,
   ... etc
  ),

  ... etc

); );
```

The result should be removed ...

```
apply_filters('plugins_filter', Array(
   Array(
   'name' => 'My Plugin1'
   'slug' => 'plugin1'
   'version' => '1.0.2,
   ... etc
  ),
  Array(
  'name' => 'My Plugin3'
  'slug' => 'plugin3'
  'version' => '1.0.2,
  ... etc
  ),
  Array(
   'name' => 'My Plugin5'
   'slug' => 'plugin5'
   'version' => '1.0.2,
   ... etc
  ),

  ... etc

); );
```

Comment: The array elements are separated by whitespace in bash, the commas will be part of the values. Also, can't you do this in php instead of the shell? Would be much simpler.

Comment: This is the most direct way to unset a value if you know it's position:
`$ array=(one two three)`
`$ echo ${#array[@]}`
`$ unset 'array[1]'`
`$ echo ${#array[@]}`

Comment: You can remove the whole Array by `unset availablePlugins`.

Comment: @choroba If it's simple, YES, PHP can be great. Can you please give a little more details or some sample code?

Comment: @AdeelAhmed I am sorry I didn't get. Can you please give a little more details?

Comment: @user1934428 Could you please give a little more details or sample code?

Comment: I posted in my comment the statement needed to remove the array in bash named `availablePlugins`. This is what you asked in your question - or did I miss something? I don't understand why you first talk about bash arrays and later mention PHP.